# Android Equalizer Presets not effective

Tags: android, equalizer

I observe that the android EQ presets are not effectively working.Can anyone let me know a method to make the effects more intense?
Thanking you,
Sreekanth

Comment: have you resolved the issue. i am facing the same issue now. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16476156/355066

Comment: Nope I couldnot resolve the issue...

Comment: Equalizer Preset are not effective for all device. Some device don't support preset that is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I will try using a different music player. This site seems to offer a solution (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-equalizer-tools-to-get-the-best-out-of-your-android-audio/).